# package configuration only found when running CMake twice

Tags: cmake

I have CMake packages for a cross-compiled target which export their package configuration into CMAKE_BINARY_DIR. In order to find those XXXConfig.cmake files I point CMake to this directory by setting the CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH like this:

```
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})
```

For some reason this only works when invoking CMake at least twice. So e.g. running

```
cmake -Bbuild
```

the first time produces an error

> By not providing "FindXXX.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project
>   has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by
>   "XXX", but CMake did not find one.

Whereas running it again works perfectly fine?

The project which gets linked to is included with the FetchContent module. Any chance this error has something to do with this?

Here is a minimal example consisting of the library **CMakeErrorLib** and the executable **CMakeError**.

First the Library:

```
# CMakeErrorLib.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.11)

project(CMakeErrorLib LANGUAGES C CXX)

add_library(CMakeErrorLib src/cmakeerrorlib)

target_include_directories(
  CMakeErrorLib
  INTERFACE $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>
            $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>
  PRIVATE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/cmakeerrorlib)

install(
  TARGETS CMakeErrorLib
  EXPORT CMakeErrorLibConfig
  ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib
  LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib)

export(
  TARGETS CMakeErrorLib
  NAMESPACE CMakeErrorLib::
  FILE "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/CMakeErrorLibConfig.cmake")
```

And the executable:

```
# CMakeError.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.11)

project(CMakeError LANGUAGES C CXX)

include(FetchContent)

# Fetching CMakeErrorLib
FetchContent_Declare(CMakeErrorLib GIT_REPOSITORY cmakerrorlib.git)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(CMakeErrorLib)

add_executable(CMakeError src/cmakeerror)

set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})
find_package(CMakeErrorLib)
target_link_libraries(CMakeError PRIVATE CMakeErrorLib)
```

And here is the whole thing as ready-to-use repo:
https://gitlab.com/higaski/CMakeError

Comment: Do not **describe** a code. Instead, **show** that code (in form of [mcve]).

Comment: Yeah I figured, just took me a while. I've added a simple repo which reproduces the error. As mentioned before it requires cmake -Bbuild to be run twice before it finds the package configuration file.

Comment: On Stack Overflow we strongly want the code to be **in the question post** itself, not *linked*. See [ask]. You basically have two relatively small `CMakeLists.txt`'s, why don't to add them (as text) into the question post? You may still give a link to the repos with "ready-to-use" CMake projects.

Comment: Concerning the problem: You inner project (which is included via `FetchContent_MakeAvailable`) creates `CMakeErrorLibConfig.cmake` script and "publishes" that script with `export(EXPORT)` command call. So, upon next `cmake` invocation `find_package` is able to find requested script. Note, that this nevertheless is a **wrong approach**: if include the project with `FetchContent_MakeAvailable` (which is similar to `add_subdirectory` call with directory, containing inner project), then you no longer need `find_package` for use that project.

Comment: Thanks, that solved the issue.